# Magento bundle product + normal product results in invalid discount calculation for percentage promotion code

Tags: magento, promotion-code

I have added a product to basket and applied the coupon which gives the full discount "Percent of product price discount". The promotion is applied successfully.
Now I added a bundle product to basket which contain the previously added product as main product. After that I went to basket page and found that, the discount is not properly applied and total payable is in negative amount.

Does anybody have an Idea ?? how it happens ?